# Member function declared, but compiler says its not

Tags: c++, g++

This is my Position.h file:

```
#ifndef POSITION_H_
#define POSITION_H_

class Position{
    public:
    Position(int v);
    int pos();
    private:
    int value;
    bool win;

};

#endif
```

This is my Position.cpp file:

```
#include "Position.h"

Position::Position(int v):value(v){
}

int Position::pos(){
    return value;
}
```

My error is:

**Position.cpp:8: error: no 'int Position::pos()' member function declared in class 'Position'**

I've been trying to fix this for hours and the function is declared. I don't understand why this wont compile.

Comment: It compiles fine for me. What command are you using to compile?

Comment: What's your command line to g++?

Comment: Are you compiling the correct files? Are you saving the files before compiling ? Please post the code here itself. Not on some external link. Use `{}` present on the editor window to format the code. BTW, Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Try compiling with `g++ -save-temps` and reading the `Position.ii` file it creates. (This will be ENORMOUS if you include any headers from the standard library - don't freak, just scroll to the end.)  Look for the class definition.  Has it gotten mangled somehow?

Comment: Try doing a clean. It may be that your build system is getting confused.

Comment: Yea I just rm'd the files and rewrote them, I had removed the object files and everything. It compiles now for some reason. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its compiling for me... you must be doing something weird.

Comment: A few users already conveyed this in *comments* and rightly so because this is an comment not an answer.